# SubSonic Update 2.1 to 3.0

Tags: subsonic

is it a big problem to uopdate form 2.1 to 3.0?

Are there any changed features/metods, or only new added features like Linq-Support and so on?

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

It's not a big problem but it's not going to be trivial. SubSonic 3 is a complete rewrite and works in a fundamentally different way. A lot of the 2.1 features are still there (e.g. fluent interface for building queries) but you'll really need to get a good understanding of the new architecture before moving to it. I would suggest building a small project using subsonic 3, to get used to it and get an idea of the issues you'll come up against, before trying to migrate an existing project. Also have a look at the docs for 3 and watch the videos to see how it now works:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page